# Driving fine and US visa application

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, visa, criminal-records

I am about to apply for a visa to visit the US for a friend's graduation this summer. I am a non-eu national living and working in the UK.

As part of the application, I need to check a box indicating if I have any arrests, criminal convictions etc.

I don't have a criminal record but I have ever been issued a fine for a driving offense. The charge was posted to me and I was to be arraigned before court but I had moved house when the charge sheet was posted so did not receive it. A warrant was issued for my arrest and I had the police calling to inform me. I turned up at the police station and was processed for court that morning where I was fined by the judge - it was an issue with misunderstanding over how insurance works in the UK and it was on a car I was purchasing, nothing criminal.

To prevent any misunderstanding at the US visa office, I was looking at getting a police certificate but that form is just too long and frighteningly difficult to fill.

My question therefore is if a driving misdemeanor constitutes a criminal offense and if it's worth the gamble applying for a tourist visa without a police certificate.

[Sorry for the lengthy question]

Comment: Does the application specifically exclude misdemeanors and/or traffic offenses from having to be listed? The problem is, even if it did, your failure to appear (whether your actual fault or not) caused a warrant to be issued for your arrest which may have made it a criminal issue, even if that was resolved by your subsequent surrender.

Answer (score 1):

From a [US Embassy website](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-waiver-program/additional-requirements/):

> If you have a minor traffic offense which did not result in an arrest
>   and/or conviction you may travel visa free under the Visa Waiver
>   Program, provided you are otherwise qualified. If you are not sure
>   whether or not you are eligible to travel visa free, the only way to
>   resolve this question is to apply for a visa.

However, as you mentioned, you did briefly have a warrant for your arrest. That causes a small wrinkle, but [these lawyers describe the conditions well](http://www.sydneycriminallawyers.com.au/blog/can-i-get-a-visa-to-usa-if-i-have-a-criminal-record/):

For ESTA, having an arrest warrant "normally won’t provided that you pass the requirements of the ‘ESTA’; or Electronic System for Travel Authorization."

ESTA asks:

"Have you ever been arrested or convicted for an offense or crime involving moral turpitude or a violation related to a controlled substance; or have been arrested or convicted for two or more offences for which the aggregate sentence to confinement was five years or more; or have been a controlled substance trafficker; or are you seeking entry to engage in criminal or immoral activities?"

So as an unpaid traffic fine is not under this, you'll be ok.

(note, I am not a lawyer, I just quote their websites)